# Having trouble getting GET variables from url

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, network-programming

I'm having trouble with this algorithm to extract the get variables from a url and print them each on a new line like:

```
x=y
z=hello
```

etc. but instead it prints a seemingly random section of the url with no newlines to the file. There must be a logic error of some kind but i just can't spot it.

```
for(i_m=0;i_m<len_m;i_m++) {

if(var_m[i_m]=='&') {
    fwrite(var_m+offset_m, 1, amp_m, echo_out);
    fputc('\n',echo_out);
    offset_m+=amp_m;
    amp_m=0;
}

amp_m++;
}
```

any help appreciated.

EDIT:
thank you everyone for your comments, I corrected that error Guss but to no avail. I thought up another algorithm, since I can't use c++ strings in this one

```
while((i_m=(strchr(var_m,'&')-var_m))>0) {  
    var_m[i_m]='\n';  
}
```

Which would change each of the & to a newline, and then I could just write var_m to the file, but for some reason this gives me a buffer overflow.

Comment: Can you please comment your code more?  If your code isn't working, and there aren't any comments explaining what the variables are/mean or what the general idea is, then it can be super hard to spot the error.  Is it a logic error (the algorithm flat-out doesn't work), or a programming error (you didn't encode your design correctly)?

Answer (score 0):

```
void StringExplode(std::string &str, const std::string &separator, std::vector<string>* results){
    int found;
    found = str.find_first_of(separator);
    while(found != string::npos){
        if(found > 0){
            results->push_back(str.substr(0,found));
        }
        str = str.substr(found+1);
        found = str.find_first_of(separator);
    }
    if(str.length() > 0){
        results->push_back(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: `StringExplode("a,b", ",", 0)` bang, you're dead. Use a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: std::vector<std::string> x;
StringExplode("a,b", ",", &x);

Comment: I'm aware of how it's intended to be used. I'm saying you have no checks for null, and that such a thing is completely unecessary anyway. If you just make the parameter a reference, you're not only simplify the use both inside and outside the function, you're guaranteed you'll have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

your accounting of offset_m and amp_m seems to be wrong. Take for example the simple string "a&b&c" - your code should have outputed from that the text:

```
a
b
c
```

but if you trace through the code you will see that when you get to the first `&` then `offset_m=0` and `amp_m=1` and you'd print `a` - which is Ok but when you get to the second `&` then `offset_m=1` and `amp_m=2` which would actually print `&b` and at no point you'd print the last element.

Using a simple string splitting algorithm like mysqlforums suggested is a common way to handle this task, but I believe you should be able to come up with a simple loop algorithm that will get you what you need. think about it again and try to run through the algorithm in your head (or using pen and paper) to try to understand how it works - I'm sure you'll get it!

If you're still having problems, post something here and I'll try to help again.